# How do you toggle insertBefore or InsertAfter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tab button. With a upward pointing arrow and text underneith. When you click the tab. The header of the site is hidden and the arrow icon turns upside down.

I would also like the arrow to change its positioning in html.

I can accomplish this with just fine using the following script:

```
<script>    
    $('.contentTab').on('click', function(e) {
      $('.mainContent').toggleClass("closeHeader");
      $('.triangle-up').toggleClass("triangle-down");
      $(".triangle-down").insertAfter(".contentTab h1")
      e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

//

**My question is:** How do I toggle this feature. So that if the *contentTab* is clicked again. The *arrow* reverts to its old positioning. Do i create an if statment? I am pretty new with **JS**

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to move the element in the first place? Normally your css classes and style rules would take care of everything needed

Comment: Because the only way to move it under the element below it would be to set it to absolute positioning and require me to re-center the element. This way I dont have to make a mess.

Comment: Josh gave a great answer. It would be even better if you posted more code or made a fiddle so people don't have to guess about what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're toggling a class on the element, you could simply use the [`:not()` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to select `.triangle-up` if it doesn't have a `.triangle-down` class:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/99th1w75/)

```
$(".triangle-down").insertAfter(".contentTab h1");
$(".triangle-up:not(.triangle-down)").insertBefore(".contentTab h1");
```

Full code snippet:

```js
$('.contentTab').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.mainContent').toggleClass("closeHeader");
  $('.triangle-up').toggleClass("triangle-down");
  $(".triangle-down").insertAfter(".contentTab h1");
  $(".triangle-up:not(.triangle-down)").insertBefore(".contentTab h1");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
.triangle-down {
  color: #f00;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contentTab">
  <span class="triangle-up">▲</span>
  <h1>Content tab header</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: true.. but you don't know that before `.contentTab h1` is the original position..

Comment: @Pamblam The OP didn't state the initial position. I'm just providing an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.contentTab').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.mainContent').toggleClass("closeHeader");
  $('.triangle-up').toggleClass("triangle-down");

  if(!$('.triangle-up').hasClass("triangle-down")){
      $(".triangle-down").insertAfter(".contentTab h1");
  }else{
      // put it back wherever it was before
      $(".triangle-down").insertAfter(...where ever it was before..);
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>    
    $('.contentTab').on('click', function(e) {
        $('.mainContent').toggleClass("closeHeader");
        if ($('.mainContent').hasClass("closeHeader")){
            $('.triangle-up').hide();
            $(".triangle-down").show();
        }else {
            $('.triangle-up').show();
            $(".triangle-down").hide();
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

provided that `.triangle-up` and `.triangle-down` are two elements.